# Statsmodels: ols writing Formula with unknown column names

Tags: python, syntax, statsmodels, anova

I am trying to run ANOVA using statsmodels, for which I was making models for every column (categorical feature) in my dataframe wrt to one column 'imp' as follows in a loop.

```
for cat_feature in df:
  data_model = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': df[cat_feature],
    'y': df['imp']})
  model = smf.ols('y ~ x',data=data_model).fit()
  res = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=1)
```

But what I would like to do is this:

```
smf.ols(df['imp'] ~ df[cat_feature],data=df).fit()
```

but this isn't the right syntax.

without having to make the data_model each time with one of its column always the same.

Is it possible?

or simply put

```
model = smf.ols('A~B', data=df).fit()
```

works but

```
model2 = smf.ols(df.A ~ df.B, data=df).fit()
```

doesn't.

Comment: What are the values in `df[cat_feature]`, numeric or strings or something else?

Comment: strings. `model2 = smf.ols('df.A ~ df.B', data=df).fit()` worked though. Since the names weren't important to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula interface, lower case `ols` in contrast to upper case `OLS`, needs a formula string as first argument.

So, I think you want string concatenation

```
smf.ols('imp ~' + cat_feature, data=df).fit()
```

Specifying pandas Series and DataFrames or numpy arrays only works with the main class `OLS`

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
model2 = sm.OLS(df['imp'], df[cat_feature]).fit()
```

As background information:

`OLS` is the actual model class
`ols` from formula.api is just a convenient alias for the method `OLS.from_formula` that preprocesses the formula information before creating an `OLS` instance.

The character `~` is a required element of the formula string, but it is not valid to separate arguments in regular python classes, methods or functions.

One crucial distinction between the array/dataframe and the formula interface:

The array interface, i.e. using OLS as in
`sm.OLS(df['imp'], df[cat_feature])`
does not do any preprocessing of the data, i.e. `exog` is taken as is. Specifically, no constant is added and categorical features are not encoded in some numerical dummy or contrast representation.

The formula interface uses `patsy` that preprocesses the data, in large parts identically to R's formulas. This means that a constant is added by default and any non-numeric columns, like those that contain strings, are processes as categorical or factor variables.